# How can I simulate an NTC on LTspice?

Tags: ltspice, temperature, thermistor

I have a schematic for a temperature controlled device which should operate at a particular temperature.

For that I am using an NTC, now I have done the math by hand but it is more efficient and effective to include a diagram and an LTspice simulation, how could I model an NTC as the parameters such as "B-Curve" and ABC for the Steinhart and Hart equations are the only ones that change?

Comment: I know that there are NTC Spice models.  Try a Gopogle search.

Comment: If you can, register in the LTspice Yahoo Groups and search the files section for NTC. There are models in there, at the very least something to get you started with.

Comment: From your question, it is hard to tell how far into the problem you are or what you've already tried. If you need a NTC model, you can try https://www.vishay.com/docs/29170/ltspice.pdf which has a link to some models and describes the modeling process. From there you can go into the .lib that defines the model, and see how it is parameterized. Does that take you in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

The way that I would do this to try different NTC's in a simulation would be to set a few parameters, I only did this for the regular beta equation and not for the full three parameter equation, but this shows you what is possible. (the three parameter equation would take a lot more time to set up)

Rtherm2 is set by parameters, you could set up A B C parameters and equations, it's also possible to set up interm equations (see [b-sources section here](http://ltwiki.org/?title=Undocumented_LTspice))

Rtherm1 is the way I prefer to test circuits with NTC's you can set a range of resistance values by looking at a table ( a high and low value) and then run a simulation with the values ramping between high and low.

[image]